# Showing error in fname and working directory even after importing os in jupyter notebook, Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, operating-system, working-directory

I am currently working with TROPOMI data. To explore the intricate parts (metadata, QA etc) of data. Run this code for import libraries in Jupyter notebook in Windows.

```
#Block 1: Import libraries
#Library to perform array operations
import numpy as np
#Library for accessing files in the directory
import os
#Library to read in netCDF files
from netCDF4 import Dataset
```

```
#Block 2: Open a TROPOMI netCDF4 data file

#Select TROPOMI product ('CO' or 'NO2')
data_product = 'CO'

#Enter file name
file_path = os.getcwd()
if data_product == 'CO':
    file_name = 'S5P_OFFL_L2__CO_____20181101T072905_20181101T091035_05447_01_010200_20181107T065627.nc'
if data_product == 'NO2':
    file_name = 'S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20181101T072905_20181101T091035_05447_01_010200_20181107T092435.nc'
    fname = [file_path + file_name]

#Set the file name to read
file_id = Dataset(fname)
```

**Output:**

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16108\271847607.py in <module>
     13 
     14 #Set the file name to read
---> 15 file_id = Dataset(fname)

NameError: name 'fname' is not defined
```

Even after importing libraries, why it does not read the working directory?

I saved these S5P files in the Current working directory.

Comment: Unless you haven't posted enough code, it just looks like a coding error. You have in Block#2, `data_product = 'CO'` So that means `if data_product == 'CO':` is true and then that gets run and sets `file_name`. The next conditional is `if data_product == 'NO2':`, which is false and so the indented block below that isn't run. That block that isn't executed is the only code I see that sets `fname`. And so `fname` is undefined and you get the error you see. **Should `fname = [file_path + file_name]` be unindented?** I don't see why you think it is importing or reading working directory issuse?

Answer (score 0):

Unindent `fname = [file_path + file_name]`.
Try in block#2:

```py
#Enter file name
file_path = os.getcwd()
if data_product == 'CO':
    file_name = 'S5P_OFFL_L2__CO_____20181101T072905_20181101T091035_05447_01_010200_20181107T065627.nc'
if data_product == 'NO2':
    file_name = 'S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20181101T072905_20181101T091035_05447_01_010200_20181107T092435.nc'
fname = [file_path + file_name]
```

See my comment below your post for the full reasoning.

Comment: os.chdir = (path), it solved my problem